# Openssl telling certificate has expired when it has not

Tags: openssl, certificate

I'm having an issue with `curl` and `openssl` reporting a client certificate as expired, even though it's notAfter date is in the future:

```
# echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect example.com:443 2>&1 | grep Verify
    Verify return code: 10 (certificate has expired)
```

But

```
# echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect example.com:443 2>&1 | openssl x509 -noout -dates
notBefore=Oct 17 00:00:00 2011 GMT
notAfter=Oct 21 12:00:00 2014 GMT
```

System date is correct. Firefox is not showing any error for that site's cert either. Openssl versions I tried are `OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013` and `OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014`. I've found a similar-looking issue [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mailing.openssl.users/b9bOO85cpWE) where the author claims that the issue is missing in openssl 0.9.8, but present in 1.0.1.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you get the results you expect if you try your commands without the `-showcerts` option?  Also, do you get the results you expect if you try your commands against sites with known valid certificates (like paypal.com, citibank.com, etc.)?

Comment: Try adding `-tls1 -servername foo.example.com`. I'm guessing you have a front-end server that's providing a default domain for requests without SNI, and the default domain is routed to an internal server with the old certificate. When the browsers connect, they use SNI and get the server for which you have updated the certificate. Or, there could be an intermediate with an expired certificate in the chain that's being served. If you provide real information, its easier for us to help you with problems like this.

Comment: Same issue, don't know why.

Comment: @linjunhalida, mine was because one of the certificates in the hierarchy of certificates confirming this one was expired

Comment: @Fluffy Well I solve this by upgrade my OSX to 10.12 :-P

Comment: @Fluffy I am experiencing the same issue. How did you resolve this exactly?

Comment: Anyone else experiencing this problem.. what worked for me was installing the cacert.pem from mozilla by following the instructions under "The Solution" here: https://momentum.spindance.com/2015/08/problems-ruby-openssl-mac-os-x-10-10/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

My problem was that the certificate did expire, but not this particular one, but one in the signing chain.

For example, for google this command `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect google.com:443 </dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -dates` shows:

```
notBefore=Oct  6 12:37:54 2016 GMT
notAfter=Dec 29 12:28:00 2016 GMT
```

However just `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect google.com:443 </dev/null` shows not 1, but 3 certificates (enclosed in `---BEGIN/END CERTIFICATE---` parts), the first one is of google and it is the one actually checked. To verify this, I've copied (there should probably be a less manual way) the first one to `/tmp/google` and the last one to `/tmp/geotrust`, now running `openssl x509 -noout -dates < /tmp/google` gives me:

```
notBefore=Oct  6 12:37:54 2016 GMT
notAfter=Dec 29 12:28:00 2016 GMT
```

Which matches the first command's output, and `openssl x509 -noout -dates < /tmp/geotrust`:

```
notBefore=May 21 04:00:00 2002 GMT
notAfter=Aug 21 04:00:00 2018 GMT
```

Which is different and was not shown before. So in the end my problem was that for one of the higher authority certificates was indeed outdated.

And BTW as the comment to the question suggests upgrading OS to fix this issue - I imagine the cause is the same. OS comes with a bunch of root certificates, so if you have crazy old OS, some of those might expire, you can either upgrade those root certs, or the whole OS to fix the issue.

Also handy to know that running without `showcerts` gives you a nice view of the cert chain - `openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 </dev/null`:

```
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=*.google.com
   i:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
 1 s:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
 2 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
   i:/C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
---
```

All of these need not to be expired.

Answer (score 6):

I got the similar problem today and surfed here with the intention of finding the answer. Fortunately, I got the answer by myself.
Here is how I got it:

1. as I got "Verify return code: 10 (certificate has expired)" error on a box, I tried another box and didn't get the error against the same SSL site, which is actually "verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate" (acceptable to me)
2. then I thought the root cause should be within the first box seeing that error. The most possible reason could be some different CA certificates in the trust store, although I still didn't know where it was for the first box
3. to get the file impacting the cert validation verification,  I prepended "strace" before "openssl s_client ...", and carefully read the files shown in the big output area, especially the ones near the "Verify return code: 10 (certificate has expired)" error. I got 2 suspect files
4. I ran "openssl x509 -text -in {filename}" for validating the 2 files, and succeeded to confirm one of them was the root cause as it's expired. This is an intermediate certificate

With that being said, please check if there is any intermediate/root certificates that have expired in your local trust store (maybe /usr/lib/ssl/certs/ for openssl), which "poisons" the verification for openssl client command or curl command.

Comment: How is your answer is different from the accepted answer ?

Comment: I just added the message I got on the other box in the post above.

Comment: Great tip about using strace! Using this we found an old root certificate being loaded that had since expired. Without strace it wasnt obvious which certificate was causing the expiry error.

Answer (score 1):

If you just execute `openssl s_client -connect <server>:<port>`, it should show you at the end after the `Verify...`  line something like:

```
---
depth=3 C = SE, O = AddTrust AB, OU = AddTrust External TTP Network, CN = AddTrust External CA Root
verify error:num=10:certificate has expired
notAfter=May 30 10:48:38 2020 GMT
read:errno=10093
```

Basically this failure message mentions the certificate in the certificate chain that was not verified and why it happened.

Answer (score 0):

got similar issue, identified the root cause by:

```
curl -v <api-url>
```

result:

```
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=XXXXXX
*       start date: Dec 09 23:25:14 2021 GMT
*       expire date: Mar 09 23:25:13 2022 GMT
*       common name: XXXXXX
*       issuer: CN=R3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US
* NSS error -8162 (SEC_ERROR_EXPIRED_ISSUER_CERTIFICATE)
* The certificate issuer's certificate has expired.  Check your system date and time.
* Closing connection 0
```

it turns out it's due to the root ca expired:
For TLS certificates issued by Let’s Encrypt, the root certificate (DST Root CA X3) in the default chain expires on* ***September 30, 2021****.
https://blog.devgenius.io/rhel-centos-7-fix-for-lets-encrypt-change-8af2de587fe4