# Browser, s_client without SNI and expired certificate

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, certificate

When I access one of my subdomains: say https://foo.example.com in a browser and inspect the certificates, the certificate looks great.  When I use openssl from a remote computer it shows an expired certificate.  How can this be?

I tried to reproduce what was found in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24992976/openssl-telling-certificate-has-expired-when-it-has-not), but my scenario is different.  When I run

```
echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect foo.example.com:443 2>&1 | grep Verify
```

I see:

```
Verify return code: 10 (certificate has expired)
```

When I run:

```
echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect foo.example.com:443 2>&1 | openssl x509 -noout -dates
```

I get:

```
notBefore=Sep 27 15:10:20 2014 GMT
notAfter=Sep 27 15:10:20 2015 GMT
```

It looks expired but the browser doesn't show it as expired.  Here it is in the browser:

[image]

Comment: Try adding `-tls1 -servername foo.example.com`. I'm guessing you have a front-end server that's providing a default domain for requests without SNI, and the default domain is routed to an internal server with the old certificate. When the browsers connect, they use SNI and get the server for which you have updated the certificate. Or, there could be an intermediate with an expired certificate in the chain that's being served. If you provide real information, its easier for us to help you with problems like this.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: @jww You were right.  When I added the tls1 info like you suggested it showed the appropriate dates.  Thank you for your help.  While I suppose you are right that Super User might be more appropriate, SO is littered with openssl questions and I encountered this issue in direct relation to deploying my software.  Development tools and software are certainly relevant questions for this site.

Comment: Don't take offense at the close. It was not a bad question other than hiding the real server name from us (which happens often). You're right about the cross-contamination, and its the reason I try to get post-2012 question tagged with the comment. If folks don't know where to ask questions on using the tools for dev ops, then its shame on us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the 1st comment by @jww.  He pointed out that I needed to add `-tls1 -servername foo.example.com` to my openssl command.  His comment:

> Try adding -tls1 -servername foo.example.com. I'm guessing you have a front-end server that's providing a default domain for requests without SNI, and the default domain is routed to an internal server with the old certificate. When the browsers connect, they use SNI and get the server for which you have updated the certificate. Or, there could be an intermediate with an expired certificate in the chain that's being served. If you provide real information, its easier for us to help you with problems like this.